# Books covering how to conduct a meta-anlysis

Tags: meta-analysis

I would like to know if anyone could recommend a book that deals more with the practical issues around conducting a meta-analysis?

Thanking you in advance

Andrew Vitiello

Answer (score 4):

I asked this question last week and obtained two excellent answers.  The question is readily accessible through links on your "meta-analysis" tag.  Here's the URL:

[Looking for good introductory treatment of meta-analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1963/looking-for-good-introductory-treatment-of-meta-analysis)

Comment: I think it is better to put a comment and vote for closing the question. Indeed it may be a bit confusing to have an answer wich is a link to a question on the same site... I voted to close the question.

Comment: @Robin: Thank you for the suggestion.  I do not see how it would be any more or less confusing to place a link in an answer or a comment, though.  I, too, have voted to close the question, but I first waited a day for the poster to respond to Shane's suggestion that this question be edited.

Comment: my view is that answering a question is a step toward accepting it in the site.

Comment: @Robin: Thank you; that makes sense and it's a principle that will help in future cases.

Comment: Three years later, the issue has come up again via comments on [another duplicate](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/80922/32036) :P See also [this meta-CV question on the broader issue](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/1867/32036).